# How does tor browser know there is an onion site available for the URL?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I open a clear net site like torproject.org in the Tor Browser, the browser shows me this:[image]

How does it know there is a onion site available for the URL?

Is there a file that maps clear site URLs to their dark net counterparts that is bundled with the browser?

Or does it magically discovers the hidden URLs somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is done by:

```
Onion-Location: http://2gzyxa5ihm7nsggfxnu52rck2vv4rvmdlkiu3zzui5du4xyclen53wid.onion/index.html
```

header when accessing https:///www.torproject.org.

The header is shortly described here: https://support.torproject.org/onionservices/onion-location/ :

> What ".onion available" means in my browser?
>
> Onion-Location is a new HTTP header that web sites can use to
> advertise their onion counterpart. If the web site that you're
> visiting has an onion site available, a purple suggestion pill will
> prompt at the URL bar saying ".onion available". When you click on
> ".onion available", the web site will be reloaded and redirected to
> its onion counterpart. At the moment, Onion-Location is available for
> Tor Browser desktop (Windows, macOS and GNU/Linux). You can learn more
> about Onion-Location in the [Tor Browser Manual](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/onion-services/). If you're an onion
> service operator, [learn how to configure Onion-Location](https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/onion-location) in your onion
> site.

Comment: tldr: add `<meta http-equiv="onion-location" content="http://youronionserviceaddress.onion">` to your html `<head>`. see also [Metalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink) to declare multiple mirrors